# Mocha timing out when test in Promise callback fails

Tags: mocha.js, es6-promise

If I have the following module:

```
module.exports = kontinue => {
  Promise.resolve({error:null})
    .then(o => {
      console.log('promise resolved');
      // say something goes wrong here
      if(true)
        kontinue({error:'promise resolved but something else went wrong'});
      else kontinue(o);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('caught error');
      kontinue({error:'promise rejected, or resolved but then continuation threw exception'})
    });
};
```

And the following test:

```
const assert = require('assert').strict;
const target = require('./the_above_code.js');

it('should not timeout', (done) => {
  target((sut) => {
    console.log('continuation called');
    assert.ok(false); // the test for sut.error === what I expected was failing
    done();
  });
});
```

It outputs:

```
promise resolved
continuation called
caught error

...

Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I realise this is because the .catch() is returning a new promise which is not resolving, but that's not what I really want during testing.

How do I test the object a promise resolves to, fail the test if necessary, have Mocha report that failure?

Perhaps there is somewhere else other than in the continuation (which never returns in the code that uses this module) that I can put the tests?

I'm sure monads can reduce the amount of boilerplate code here, but using them surely would violate [Kernighan's maxim](http://www.defprogramming.com/q/188353f216dd/).

Comment: What if you type return on Promise.resolve()?

Comment: @squeekyDave I removed the braces so that the arrow function returned the result of `Promise.resolve().then().catch()` and it still timed out. I also tried removing the `done` parameter from the callback supplied to `it()` but that meant `assert.ok(false)` no longer caused a test failure.

Comment: I don't know how useful this will be but I faced a similar issue not long ago and the solution of my problem was to use a beforeEach hook where I typed this.timeout=10000. It was something like beforeEach(function(){ this.timeout=1000;
// then i loaded my variable that returned a prmise
})
And after that I was able to test. Hope this helps.

Comment: @squeekyDave thanks, but my problem is not that the operation takes longer than the time-out duration (which increasing the timeout would solve), but rather that the test assertion throws an exception within the .then() and I don't know where else I can put it.